# Directly editing PDF with pen device

Tags: pdf

does anyone know what kind of field I would have to put to PDF that would allow me to draw a signature into it. I have a pen device connected to my PC. With this device I would like to sign PDF. PDF must not allow me to put signature anywhere else except the pre inserted empty field. The process of signing must be the same like I would sign physical document. Currently I have solution where you click sign where then pops up window where you then put signature. This solution is not good because you don't directly sign PDF's.

Best Regards, Igor

Comment: The PDF specification does not define a field for such a purpose. BTW: *The process of signing must be the same like I would sign physical document* - when signing a physical document, I can scribble anywhere on it, resulting in a more or less valid signature and an arbitrary amount of changes to the original document content.

Comment: With same process I mean that you would sign document like it would be physical. With field in PDF I would limit area where you could sign. In physical shape you can't limit signature area. In digital world we could take an advantage and be a little smarter.